# Cannot configure vimtex with global variable

Tags: config, neovim, packer

I use neovim as my default editor for latex. After install `vimtex` with `packer.nvim`, however, I cannot configure `vimtex` with its global variables which bothers me a lot.

I tried to set global variables with the following ways but both of them don't work.

```
vim.cmd([[
    let g:vimtex_compiler_latexmk = {
        \ 'executable' : 'latexmk',
        \ 'build_dir' : '.out',  
]])
```

or

```
vim.g.vimtex_compiler_latexmk = {
    executable = 'latexmk',
    build_dir = '.out'
}
```

I feel that `vimtex` doesn't load the `vimtex_complier_latexmk`, as a result, .tex isn't built into `.out`. However, I can successfully print `g:vimtex_compiler_latexmk` in command mode and it's the correct output.

Some info:

- I install `vimtex` with `packer.nvim`
- vimtexinfo

```
System info:
  OS: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
  Vim version: NVIM v0.9.1
  Has clientserver: true
  Servername: /run/user/1000/nvim.375393.0

VimTeX project: main
  base: main.tex
  root: /tmp
  tex: /tmp/main.tex
  main parser: current file verified
  document class: article
  packages: amsbsy amsfonts amsgen amsmath amsopn amssymb amstext atbegshi atveryend auxhook babel bigintcalc bitset environ epstopdf-base etexcmds etoolbox everyshi fancyvrb fontenc geometry gettitlestring graphics graphicx hycolor hyperref iftex ifvtex infwarerr inputenc intcalc keyval kvdefinekeys kvoptions kvsetkeys letltxmacro ltxcmds nameref newverbs pdfescape pdftexcmds pgf pgfcomp-version-0-65 pgfcomp-version-1-18 pgfcore pgfrcs pgfsys refcount rerunfilecheck shortvrb soul soulutf8 tcolorbox textcomp trig trimspaces uniquecounter url verbatim xcolor
  compiler: latexmk
    engine: -pdf
    options:
      -verbose
      -file-line-error
      -synctex=1
      -interaction=nonstopmode
    callback: 1
    continuous: 1
    executable: latexmk
  viewer: General
  qf method: LaTeX logfile
```

neovim information:

```
NVIM v0.9.1
Build type: RelWithDebInfo
LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3
Compilation: /usr/bin/cc -O2 -g -Og -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wno-unused-parameter -Wstrict-prototypes -std=gnu99 -Wshadow -Wconversion -Wvla -Wdouble-promotion -Wmissing-noreturn -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-common -Wno-unused-result -Wimplicit-fallthrough -fdiagnostics-color=always -fstack-protector-strong -DUNIT_TESTING -DINCLUDE_GENERATED_DECLARATIONS -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/build/nvim/parts/nvim/build/.deps/usr/include/luajit-2.1 -I/usr/include -I/build/nvim/parts/nvim/build/.deps/usr/include -I/build/nvim/parts/nvim/build/build/src/nvim/auto -I/build/nvim/parts/nvim/build/build/include -I/build/nvim/parts/nvim/build/build/cmake.config -I/build/nvim/parts/nvim/build/src -I/usr/include -I/build/nvim/parts/nvim/build/.deps/usr/include -I/build/nvim/parts/nvim/build/.deps/usr/include -I/build/nvim/parts/nvim/build/.deps/usr/include -I/build/nvim/parts/nvim/build/.deps/usr/include -I/build/nvim/parts/nvim/build/.deps/usr/include -I/build/nvim/parts/nvim/build/.deps/usr/include
```

Comment: By the way. I have the same issue for `maplocalleader` as well.

Comment: From the documentation `:h g:vimtex_compiler_latexmk` it seems that there is no `build_dir` option but only `out_dir`. Doesn't explain why you can't specify `maplocalleader`. You might want to post an actual minimal `init.lua` file (which others can run) instead of code snippets. In your first snippet there's a closing `}` missing for instance.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I was careless. I just copy-pased from my previous vimtex configuration without looking up the documentation. Thank you for pointing it out. Really appreciate.